# Is there a way to get access to the Cassandra schema info using the spark-cassandra connector?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

The newer spark-cassandra connector has deprecated/removed the CassandraSQLContext which allowed one to execute CQL. And, now, I cannot find a way to find catalog info like : list of keyspaces, tables within a keyspace or column meta data.

Specifically, I want to be able to run something like `select keyspace_name, table_name, column_name, type from system_schema.columns where keyspace_name = 'test'`
Maybe I missed API to run CQL? ( I am using the 2.0 connector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark Cassandra connector has `withSessionDo` method that you can use, the same way as you do in Java driver, like this (adopted from [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md)):

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector

CassandraConnector(conf).withSessionDo { session =>
  session.execute("select keyspace_name, table_name, column_name, 
      type from system_schema.columns where keyspace_name = 'test';")
}
```

But you can use much simpler RDD operations, like this:

```
sc.cassandraTable("system_schema", "columns").select("keyspace_name","table_name", 
     ...other columns...)
```

P.S. Also, please notice that access via `Metadata` class that is possible to obtain via Session->Cluster is more portable way to do it.